# Override default DateTime 12:00 AM or 12:00PM to current Time?

Tags: customization, acumatica

As in my picture I have DateTime of SLA and Finish Date, and Finish Date is the same value of SLA but it allows user to add or change the DateTime. When I change the DateTime on Finish Date, it got the default value of Time was 12:00 PM or 12:00 AM. Is there any way to change the default time to current time? and will there be any impact if user changes the user locale format?

[image]

This is my UsrFinishDate default value:

UsrFinishDate (New Field)

```
 [PXDBDate(PreserveTime = true)]
 [PXUIField(DisplayName="Finish Date")]
```

```cs
protected void CRCase_UsrFinishDate_FieldDefaulting(PXCache cache, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
{
    CRCase row = e.Row as CRCase;
    CRCaseExt rowExt = PXCache<CRCase>.GetExtension<CRCaseExt>(row);

    if (row == null || row.AssignDate == null) return;

    if (row.ClassID != null && row.Severity != null)
    {
        var severity = (CRClassSeverityTime)PXSelect<CRClassSeverityTime,
                       Where<CRClassSeverityTime.caseClassID, Equal<Required<CRClassSeverityTime.caseClassID>>,
                       And<CRClassSeverityTime.severity, Equal<Required<CRClassSeverityTime.severity>>>>>
                       .Select(Base, row.ClassID, row.Severity);
        if (severity != null && severity.TimeReaction != null)
        {
            e.NewValue = row.SLAETA;
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }

    if (row.Severity != null && row.ContractID != null)
    {
        var template = (Contract)PXSelect<Contract, Where<Contract.contractID, Equal<Required<CRCase.contractID>>>>.Select(Base, row.ContractID);
        if (template == null) return;

        var sla = (ContractSLAMapping)PXSelect<ContractSLAMapping,
                  Where<ContractSLAMapping.severity, Equal<Required<CRCase.severity>>,
                  And<ContractSLAMapping.contractID, Equal<Required<CRCase.contractID>>>>>
                  .Select(Base, row.Severity, template.TemplateID);
        if (sla != null && sla.Period != null)
        {
            e.NewValue = row.SLAETA;
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my other event rowSelected:

```cs
protected void CRCase_RowUpdated(PXCache cache, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    var row = e.Row as CRCase;
    var oldRow = e.OldRow as CRCase;
    CRCaseExt rowExt = PXCache<CRCase>.GetExtension<CRCaseExt>(row);

    if (row == null || oldRow == null) return;

    if (row.OwnerID == null)
    {
        row.AssignDate = null;
        row.SLAETA = null;
        rowExt.UsrFinishDate = null;
    }
    else if (oldRow.OwnerID == null)
    {
        row.AssignDate = PXTimeZoneInfo.Now;
        if (row == null || row.AssignDate == null) return;

        if (row.ClassID != null && row.Severity != null)
        {
            var severity = (CRClassSeverityTime)PXSelect<CRClassSeverityTime,
                                Where<CRClassSeverityTime.caseClassID, Equal<Required<CRClassSeverityTime.caseClassID>>,
                                And<CRClassSeverityTime.severity, Equal<Required<CRClassSeverityTime.severity>>>>>.
                                Select(Base, row.ClassID, row.Severity);
            if (severity != null && severity.TimeReaction != null)
            {
                row.SLAETA = ((DateTime)row.AssignDate).AddMinutes((int)severity.TimeReaction);
                rowExt.UsrFinishDate = ((DateTime)row.AssignDate).AddMinutes((int)severity.TimeReaction);
            }
        }

        if (row.Severity != null && row.ContractID != null)
        {
            var template = (Contract)PXSelect<Contract, Where<Contract.contractID, Equal<Required<CRCase.contractID>>>>.Select(Base, row.ContractID);
            if (template == null) return;

            var sla = (ContractSLAMapping)PXSelect<ContractSLAMapping,
                              Where<ContractSLAMapping.severity, Equal<Required<CRCase.severity>>,
                              And<ContractSLAMapping.contractID, Equal<Required<CRCase.contractID>>>>>.
                              Select(Base, row.Severity, template.TemplateID);
            if (sla != null && sla.Period != null)
            {
                row.SLAETA = ((DateTime)row.AssignDate).AddMinutes((int)sla.Period);
                rowExt.UsrFinishDate = ((DateTime)row.AssignDate).AddMinutes((int)sla.Period);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by current time ? Current time like at this very moment or current time as the same of SLA (3:58 PM) ?

Comment: @SimonML, I want the current time like at this very moment for sure.

Comment: Which screen are you customizing ?

Comment: CRCase (ScreenId=CR306000)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the definition of the field I added to the Case screen, note the `PreserveTime = true` which I think might be  what you are missing.

```cs
public class CRCaseExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CR.CRCase>
{
    #region UsrFinishDate

    [PXDBDate(PreserveTime = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Finish Date")]
    public virtual DateTime? UsrFinishDate { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrFinishDate : IBqlField { }

    #endregion
}
```

And here is an easy way to set the current time when the UsrFinishDate value is changed. Don't forget to set the `CommitChanges` for that field.

```cs
protected virtual void CRCase_UsrFinishDate_FieldUpdating(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatingEventArgs e)
{
    CRCase currentCase = (CRCase)e.Row;
    var caseExt = PXCache<CRCase>.GetExtension<CRCaseExt>(currentCase);
    if (caseExt == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    e.NewValue = new DateTime(caseExt.UsrFinishDate.Value.Year,
                                                caseExt.UsrFinishDate.Value.Month,
                                                caseExt.UsrFinishDate.Value.Day,
                                                DateTime.Now.Hour,
                                                DateTime.Now.Minute,
                                                DateTime.Now.Second);
}
```

Comment: Anyways, if the default value of UsrFinishDate from the SLA and then user can change it. So I should change this caseExt.UsrFinishDate.Value.Year to case.SLAETA.Value.Year, right?

Comment: So you want to choose a datefor `UsrFinishDate` but keep the same year that is currently selected in the `SLA`, right?  Then yes you just have to replace `caseExt.UsrFinishDate.Value.Year` with `currentCase.SLAETA.Value.Year`. Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130(v=vs.110).aspx for the datetime constructor that I used

Comment: but why it got error "Nullable object must have the value" of UsrFinishDate?

Comment: Update your original post and put your code so we can check this out

Comment: I mean post your code here so we can have a look at it

Comment: Your coding and mine, the result were the same for the default value but when the user change the Finish Date, it still get the default time of 12:00 AM or 12:00 PM the same.

Comment: @meimei Can you show me your DAC and its extension ?

Comment: if you have users crossing time zones you might want to set UseTimeZone = true in your PXDateTime attribute. This way each user should see the time related to their local time zone settings

Comment: @Brendan, so if user select change the field UsrFinishDate, it will get the current time right?

Comment: you still need the preservetime = true as simon mentioned, but i was making sure if you had users in multi time zones to be aware that they might want to see the time based on their local time zones. Otherwise all time zones would show the same time regardless of which time zone will view your date field.

Comment: @Brendan, for what I've done, I got the default value DateTime was correct. But when I change it, it didn't get the current time. Please help.

Comment: in your page do you have the commit changes as simon mentioned?  for times in Acumatica you can also use PX.Common.PXTimeZoneInfo.UtcNow or PX.Common.PXTimeZoneInfo.Now. I would use UtcNow to make sure all users are consistante in time as long as the page is translating the displayed time to the users local time zone

Comment: I've already added PX.Common.PXTimeZoneInfo.UtcNow or PX.Common.PXTimeZoneInfo.Now to my coding above but first time it got the current time was correct. But when I change date it still get the default time by 12:00 AM or 12:00 PM.